# Oracle database error "space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USERS'_ "

Tags: oracle, liferay-6

I am getting following error while executing script from application :

```
ORA-30032: the suspended (resumable) statement has timed out_ORA-01536: space quota exceeded for tablespace 'USERS'_
```

Answer (score 1):

#### in the first place:

The error you are hitting (`ORA-01536`) is complaining about the permissions of the user you are logged in.
That user is trying to add data to a table that belongs to a tablespace named `USERS`.
A tablespace is a logical container that hides the physical storage behind the persistence of a table, and each table is explicitly or implicitly assigned a tablespace upon creation (if not specified, the tablespace is a assigned the "default" tablespace associated to the user when the user was created, often the `USERS` tablespace).

If you want your user have no restrictions on the amount of data it puts in `USERS`, run:

```
ALTER USER <your user> quota unlimited on USERS;
```

or if you want to limit the quota to, say, 10 MB:

```
alter user <your user> quota 10M on USERS;
```

See [Managing Users and Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96521/users.htm#15298) for more details.

#### secondly:

**If you are just playing around** with your database and don't want to have any space restriction (e.g. you are not using a production database), run either of the following:

```
grant resource to <your user> ;
--or
grant unlimited tablespace to <your user> ;
```

Note that the above statements must be executed by another user, and that other user must have the power to grant the relevant permissions to others (for instance log in `as SYSDBA`). If you execute them from your user, or the user has not the proper grants, the statements will fail.

#### by the way:

`ORA-30032` is just sort of a wrapper for your real error, simply indicating that the DB has suspended your session waiting a bit for you to fix the tablespace allocation problem, until a timeout made it give up (see [Resumable timeout explained](https://oraclespin.com/2011/08/01/resumable-timeout-explained/)).

Comment: See also [How can I check if a user have a quota on tablespace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152573/how-can-i-check-if-a-user-have-a-quota-on-tablespace).